# User image as Open Graph object - iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create an Open Graph Object with user generated photo uploaded to the staging resources in order to post an Action with it. I am using the latest Facebook SDK(3.5)  for iOS.
The code is as follows:

```
[FBRequestConnection startForUploadStagingResourceWithImage:self.image completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error){
            NSString *uri = [result valueForKey:@"uri"];

            NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost];
            object.provisionedForPost = YES;
            object[@"type"] = @"<APP_NAME>:<OBJECT_NAME>";
            object[@"url"] = uri;
            object[@"title"] = @"My Title";
            object[@"user_generated"] = @"true";

            [FBRequestConnection startForPostOpenGraphObject:object
                                           completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

    }];
}];
```

In the completion block of *`startForPostOpenGraphObject`:* I should call to *`startForPostWithGraphPath`* with the id of the newly created Object. However, I get no id, but an error:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x1f2f14a0 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=500, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 1;
        message = "An unknown error has occurred.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
code = 500;
}, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x1f2ca300, state: FBSessionStateOpen, loginHandler: 0x1f2cb750, appID: **************, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x1e56ed00>, expirationDate: 4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, refreshDate: 2013-05-08 09:07:56 +0000, `attemptedRefreshDate`: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
"user_photos",
"publish_stream",
"publish_actions"
)>}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the url and the user_generated properties needs to go under the image property, which is also an array, so something like this should work:

```
object[@"type"] = @"<APP_NAME>:<OBJECT_NAME>";
object[@"title"] = @"My Title";
object[@"image"] = @[@{@"url": uri, @"user_generated":@"true"}];
```

You can also see the Scrumptious sample on how to do it as part of a batch request.

Comment: The Scrumptious sample was very useful. Thank you.